# Import data from Google Drive folder to Power BI

Tags: import, google-drive-api, powerbi

How to import entire folder from Google Drive to Power BI?

There is some information on the web how to import specific file from Google Drive to Power BI. I would like to import entire folder with all the CSV files inside.

Update. I found these interesting hints but they look too complex for me to solve the problem:

https://www.skolenipowerbi.cz/l/google-drive-connector-kompletni-pruvodce/

https://www.thebiccountant.com/2017/09/24/custom-connector-import-google-sheets-oauth2-powerbi/

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: Your googling has turned up the solution. If it's too complex for you I don't know what advice we can offer here except:try it and ask a question if you have difficulties

Comment: You could always copy the files to OneDrive and import them more easily from there